# Angular button screen

Tags: html, angular

I have a `div` which contains a bunch of buttons. I currently look like the image, but I can't get them to be next to each other as well. It looks like a one whole column. I want to have 20 little buttons per row (I currently have 1000 buttons). How can I make them evenly spaced row wise and column wise in Angular?

HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="column wrap" fxLayoutGap="30px"  fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="mat-elevation-z2 responsive-grid">
                        <button mat-button class="green fuse-white-fg"
                            *ngFor="let prm of cell">{{prm.LocationReference}}</button>
                    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kbk6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BooTstrap grid classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to arrange buttons in row and column.

```js
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button class="col-md" style="margin:2px" *ngFor="let btn of buttons">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, I am using Bootstrap grid classes like `container`, `row` & `col-md`. And `col-md` is the one which do the job. It forms grids above screen size of `768px`.

I have also added some margin as you can see in inline style code `style="margin:2px"` to give some spacing.

This is [Stackblitz implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qmmtqp?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Remember to test in full screen as I have used `col-md`. For smaller screens, use other classes in Bootstrap docs mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this angular wiki . https://www.angularjswiki.com/flexlayout/basics/#angular-flex-layout-row-example